# Abs and checksum in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

The checksum is returning **null** in the program. And also when i try executing only the query.. i get

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Audit C recorded' to data type tinyint.
```

.. Can you please help me on this

```
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(Indicator)) % 450 AS TINYINT)   AS Indicator,
       CAST(CIndicator AS VARCHAR(100))                  AS CIndicator,
       CAST(SK_IndicatorL2 AS TINYINT)                   AS SK_IndicatorL2,
       CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(IndicatorL2)) % 450 AS TINYINT) AS IndicatorL2
FROM   ( VALUES ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Audit C recorded',
       'Audit C recorded  (excluding screen in 3y prior to start of quarter)'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Follow Up appointment',
       'Follow Up appointment'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded') ) AS Nis (Indicator, 
                                              CIndicator, 
                                              SK_IndicatorL2, 
                                              IndicatorL2)
```

I tried doing this :
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM('Audit C recorded')) % 250 as TinyInt)
I get a proper integer value.

Comment: I get `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Audit C recorded' to data type tinyint.` do you have `ANSI_WARNINGS` off? Why are you trying to convert obvious non numeric data to `tinyint` anyway?

Comment: i am trying to get the unique id based on the characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(Indicator)) % 220 AS TINYINT)   AS Indicator,
       CAST(CIndicator AS VARCHAR(100))                  AS CIndicator,
       CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(SK_IndicatorL2)) % 220 AS TINYINT) AS SK_IndicatorL2,
       CAST(IndicatorL2 AS varchar(100))                   AS IndicatorL2

FROM   ( VALUES ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Audit C recorded',
       'Audit C recorded  (excluding screen in 3y prior to start of quarter)'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Follow Up appointment',
       'Follow Up appointment'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded') ) AS Nis (Indicator, 
                                              CIndicator, 
                                              SK_IndicatorL2, 
                                              IndicatorL2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think she is trying to get the id and the name metric for this query. I am also getting the data type error.. 
CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(Indicator)) % 450 as TinyInt) as an id number 
if i am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but this works.

You need to change from `TINYINT` to `SMALLINT` as you may have a value up to 450.

**EDIT:** If you need TINYINT, just use `% 256` instead of `% 450`

```
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(Indicator)) % 256 AS TINYINT)      AS Indicator,
       CAST(CIndicator AS VARCHAR(100))                     AS CIndicator,
       CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(SK_IndicatorL2)) % 256 AS TINYINT) AS SK_IndicatorL2,
       CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(IndicatorL2)) % 256 AS TINYINT)    AS IndicatorL2
FROM   ( VALUES ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Audit C recorded',
       'Audit C recorded  (excluding screen in 3y prior to start of quarter)'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT',
       'Community Detox and TH CAT'),
                ('Alcohol',
       'Alcohol',
       'Follow Up appointment',
       'Follow Up appointment'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39',
       'HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39'),
                ('Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Healthy Lifestyles',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded',
       'Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded') ) AS Nis (Indicator, 
                                              CIndicator, 
                                              SK_IndicatorL2, 
                                              IndicatorL2)
```

And it gives this: *(Edited to update values when using `% 256`*

```
Indicator CIndicator                                                                                           SK_IndicatorL2                                                                                       IndicatorL2
--------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
167       Alcohol                                                                                              Audit C recorded                                                                                     110
167       Alcohol                                                                                              Community Detox and TH CAT                                                                           17
167       Alcohol                                                                                              Follow Up appointment                                                                                83
187       Healthy Lifestyles                                                                                   HealthyLifestyle-Aged 19-39                                                                          143
187       Healthy Lifestyles                                                                                   Aged 19-39 - BMI recorded                                                                            32
```

**UPDATE: If you really want a unique string, then you could use [HASHBYTES](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), like this:**

```
HASHBYTES('SHA', IndicatorL2) AS [HASHVAL]
```

But if you need a `TINYINT`, then your proposed solution is probably better.

Comment: Can we get the tinyint value. I d'nt mind using 250 as range value to modulate

Comment: Yes, just use `% 256` which gives a number in the range 0-255 which will work. I have changed my answer.